# Number calculation in Golang gives a different result when compared to JavaScript?

Tags: go

To sum it up, I'm trying to get the following js code converted to Go:

```
5 / 6 * variable * (2 * variable * variable + 27 * variable + 91)
```

No matter what I try I can't get it to work. This is for a Discord bot so it doesn't look exactly like Go. I'm sure this could be easily done in one line instead of multiple as well.

```
{{ $xpToLvl := (mult $desiredLvl $desiredLvl 2) }}
{{ $xpToLvl = (add $xpToLvl 27 91) }}
{{ $xpToLvl = (mult $desiredLvl $xpToLvl) }}
{{ $xpToLvl = (mult 0.8333333 $xpToLvl) | roundCeil }}
```

Full code can be found [here](https://github.com/PsKramer/mee6calc/blob/master/calc.js).

Comment: What problem are you specifically encountering? Is the calculated value not exact?

Comment: Yes, the javascript code outputs the correct value, while the Go code does not. 

Using 17 as a variable, the correct value is 15980, yet the Golang code outputs 241

Comment: The order of operations is different in Go. It adds 27 and 91 to some value, but the JS code never does that (27 is multiplied with the argument first, then added).

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript numbers don't have different types like int, float, double etc...
JavaScript numbers are always stored as double-precision floating-point numbers, following the international IEEE 754 standard.

Whereas, in Golang numbers can be represented in different types like int, float etc...

Hence,

`5 / 6 * variable * (2 * variable * variable + 27 * variable + 91)`

where `variable` is 17

**In JavaScript**
5 divided by 6(5/6) in JavaScript would be 0.8333333333333334, as implicitly it's a floating-point division(5.0/6.0)

=> 0.8333333333333334 * 17 * ( 2 * 17 * 17 + 27 * 17 + 91 )
=> 0.8333333333333334 * 17 * (1128)
=> **15980.000000000002**

**In Golang**
5 divided by 6(5/6) in Golang would be 0, as it is an integer division. Thus the result of your expression is 0.

=> 0 * 17 * ( 2 * 17 * 17 + 27 * 17 + 91 )
=> **0**

So, in order for you to get the same answer as you see in JavaScript **use float64 data type for your Golang code instead of int**.
Here's how it would look like,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {

    variable := 17.0
    result := 5.0 / 6.0 * variable * (2.0*variable*variable + 27.0*variable + 91.0)
    fmt.Println(result)
}
```

Output: 15980.000000000002

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/xjKarE0Kgnu